# The selected wizard could not be started. Plug-in org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui was unable to load class

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I load a m2 plugin in eclipse, and after this I want to create maven project, when I want to do this I get a error:

```
The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui was unable to load class  org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenImportWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui (547).
```

I read that some plugins can cause such error, say me please which plugins I must delete if the problem is a result of.

It is content of log file in .metadata

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.MavenPluginActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:398)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:402)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:573)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:293)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:288)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardElement.createExecutableExtension(WorkbenchWizardElement.java:123)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardElement.createWizard(WorkbenchWizardElement.java:261)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardNewPage$5.createWizard(NewWizardNewPage.java:737)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode$1$1.run(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:142)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode$1.run(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:124)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode.getWizard(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:120)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WizardSelectionPage.java:107)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:878)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:425)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:269)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:290)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:343)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/component/annotations/Configuration
at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusAnnotatedBeanModule$PlexusAnnotatedBeanSource.<init>(PlexusAnnotatedBeanModule.java:129)
at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusAnnotatedBeanModule.<init>(PlexusAnnotatedBeanModule.java:82)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:202)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.MavenPluginActivator.newPlexusContainer(MavenPluginActivator.java:268)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.MavenPluginActivator.start(MavenPluginActivator.java:186)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
... 112 more
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.component.annotations.Configuration cannot be found by org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.6.2.20150902-0001
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 121 more
 Root exception:
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/component/annotations/Configuration
at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusAnnotatedBeanModule$PlexusAnnotatedBeanSource.<init>(PlexusAnnotatedBeanModule.java:129)
at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusAnnotatedBeanModule.<init>(PlexusAnnotatedBeanModule.java:82)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:202)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.MavenPluginActivator.newPlexusContainer(MavenPluginActivator.java:268)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.MavenPluginActivator.start(MavenPluginActivator.java:186)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:398)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:402)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:573)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:293)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:288)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardElement.createExecutableExtension(WorkbenchWizardElement.java:123)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardElement.createWizard(WorkbenchWizardElement.java:261)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardNewPage$5.createWizard(NewWizardNewPage.java:737)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode$1$1.run(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:142)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode$1.run(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:124)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode.getWizard(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:120)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WizardSelectionPage.java:107)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:878)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:425)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:269)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:290)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:343)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.component.annotations.Configuration cannot be found by org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.6.2.20150902-0001
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 121 more
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite the right characterization of what it says on the page. Please check your .log file `/path/workspace/.metadata/`.

Find the plugin which is causing this problem and update to a version of the plugin compatible with the Eclipse version.
To find the hidden files in the workspace use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

if there is sonar plugin try removing from eclipse 'help' -> 'installation details'